# How would you compare two IP addresses to see which one is greater?

Tags: ip-address, ip

For example, following are two sets of IP addresses, now, how would you identify the greater IP for each set?

SET A:

10.192.3.177 and 10.192.2.204

SET B:

10.192.3.205 and 10.192.2.204

Thanks!!

Comment: How would **you** compare two complex numbers to see which one is greater? (Sorry about not answering your question here, it has already been answered, just had to point out that per sé, such structures are not *comparable*, unless you provide a definition to do so)

Answer (score 4):

If you convert them to a 32-bit integer, the greater one will be the greater integer. In other words:

```
10.192.3.177 -> 0x0ac003b1 (180,356,017) (bigger)
10.192.2.204 -> 0x0ac002cc (180,355,788)

10.192.3.205 -> 0x0ac003cd (180,356,045) (bigger)
10.192.2.204 -> 0x0ac002cc (180,355,788)
```

I'm having a hard time imagining a use case where it would matter but that's the approach I would take if I had to check in a program.

Comment: Not sure, but I suspect the OP is trying to sort the addresses for some data structure.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably clarify what you mean by "greater".

But the numerical (uint32) value of each IP address can be calculated with:

```
d + 256 * c + 65536 * b + 16777216 * a
```

where a, b, c, and d are the base 10 values in an IPv4 formatted:
a.b.c.d

Comment: I'd prefer something like d | (c << 8) | (b << 16) | (a << 24)

Comment: Where are getting those numbers from? They should be `256`, `65,536` and `16,777,216` (which is one reason I prefer SDX's modification).

Comment: @paxdiablo  You're right, that's what you get for late night answers :) I was trying to set something up for the asker that didn't use bit shifting or OR'ing, etc.

Comment: This is a a useful way to convert the bytes. Not sure why it was downvoted, possibly the (initially) incorrect multipliers but, since that's no longer the case, +1.

Answer (score 1):

If you're after a way to sort a list of IP's you can also store the IP in a string with each octet prepended by 0 to 3 digits.  Then a text sort works fine.

Example:

```
010.192.002.204
010.192.003.177
```